# Getting file path on saveobj and loadobj

Tags: matlab, file-io, overloading

Is it possible to get the loading or saving file path while overloading `saveobj` and `loadobj`?

Unfortunately matlab only gives you the struct to be saved or loaded, but this parameter is not given directly to us. I was wondering if there is a trick for getting this information.

Comment: I'm glad the first solution is workable when you can control the syntax of `save`.  I just posted a more generic solution that can parse out the file name when a literal string is used for the file name, BUT it must be called in a M file, not the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `evalc` to get file name variable

Say you are calling `save` using functional syntax.  For example,

```
tt = timer; % for timer/saveobj overloaded method
fname = 'test.mat'; varname = 'tt';
save(fname,varname)
```

In `saveobj`, use `evalin` to get the `fname` variable.  To quickly test with the above example, set a breakpoint at the first line of `timer\saveobj`,

```
>> dbstop in timer\saveobj
>> save(fname,varname)
23  if isvalid(obj)
K>> fname = evalin('caller','fname')
fname =
timertest.mat
K>>
```

Since `save` is a built-in command, there is no separate stack for `save`, and the caller of `saveobj` will be whatever ran the `save` command.  In this example, it is the base workspace:

```
K>> dbstack
> In timer.saveobj at 23
K>> dbup
In base workspace.
K>> dbdown
In workspace belonging to timer.saveobj at 23
```

I'm pretty sure you know how to get the path if `fname` is the full file name, but for completeness,

```
filePath = fileparts(fname) % empty when no path specified
```

### Using `dbstack` and `dbtype` to parse the `save` command

This method works only if you are calling `save` from a script - it will *not* work if `save` is typed on the command line (in the base workspace).  However, it does *not* require the file name to be in a variable.

The following code would go in your `saveobj` method:

```
[st,I]=dbstack('-completenames');
fname = regexp(evalc('dbtype(st(2).file,num2str(st(2).line))'),...
    '(?<=save\()(\S*)(?=,)','match','once');
```

For example, if our test script now uses `save` with a temporary literal,

```
>> dbstop in timer\saveobj
>> save('C:\timertest.mat',varname)
23  if isvalid(obj)
K>> st = dbstack('-completenames');
K>> fname = regexp(evalc('dbtype(st(2).file,num2str(st(2).line))'),'(?<=save\()(\S*)(?=,)','match','once')
fname =
'C:\timertest.mat'
```

You got the file name in a string, and you get get the path as before with `fileparts`.

Comment: It is a shame that matlab does not offer us the control to filepath. I've tried something similar in the past but noticed the same (save is compiled and you can't access its variables from within the matlab framework). I liked your idea, I think there is no other way since this is a limitation from the matlab framework, but it is quite limited to request user to save using only this syntax.

Comment: Sounds like you also want to handle `save` commands typed on the command line rather than just formed in a function or script of yours.  Unfortunately, it's not clear how to access a literal input argument vs. a variable in that case.  One thing I tried involved the nifty `inputname` function, but alas it does not work for temporary literal inputs, just variables.

Comment: Well, this new solution uses a feature that I was unaware of. Even though this has its limitations, your effort was of great help (at least I learned new things x) ). I will take a look at it later.

Comment: Oh, nice, you used dbstack information to get the line in the previous stack which called the save information and got the file name there. Nice idea. I didn't know about the dbtype, thanks for sharing it x)